# WPF Datagrid refresh Displaymember path empty

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid, wpf-controls

I want to Refresh my DataGrid and found the following coding on the web:

```
dataGridView.ItemsSource = null;
dataGridView.ItemsSource = ItemsSourceObjects;
```

It does work except for the string/column Names does not get displayed with the objects only the objects/items itself.

Any Ideas on why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TId}" Header="id" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="60"/>
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TChassisManufacturer}" Header="Project Name" MinWidth="122" MaxWidth="200"/>
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProjectStatusM}" Header="Status" MinWidth="122" MaxWidth="100"/>
```

Comment: you have to bind to source in XAML as well

Comment: Yes I have when populating the datagrid the columns are bind and it does work only when refreshing the datagrid it displays nothing unless I have to do another binding? @Sakura

Comment: Can you post your XAML code to show how you binding?

Comment: Updated post @Sakura

Comment: is my answer help you?

Comment: I see what you want to do but don't you think it is a little bit unnecessary in terms of  amount of coding and time? I had used a similar method before and I know there must be a better way of going about doing a refresh? @Sakura

Comment: Refresh is heavy action and you should not call it. My code auto update the items you change with best performance, so you don't have to call anything else to update datagrid.

Comment: Oh my code being hidden, Just edited. See again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

You don't need to call refresh. When you add/delete items from `my`, `dg` will auto update for you.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <DataGrid Name="dataGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TId}" Header="id" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="60"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TChassisManufacturer}" Header="Project Name" MinWidth="122" MaxWidth="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProjectStatusM}" Header="Status" MinWidth="122" MaxWidth="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<myClass> my = new ObservableCollection<myClass>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView.DataContext = my;
        my.Add(new myClass { TId = 1, TChassisManufacturer = "Sony", ProjectStatusM = "Done" });
        my.Add(new myClass { TId = 2, TChassisManufacturer = "Apple", ProjectStatusM = "Doing" });
    }
}

class myClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    int id;
    public int TId
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TId"));
        }
    }

    string name;
    public string TChassisManufacturer
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TChassisManufacturer"));
        }
    }

    string status;
    public string ProjectStatusM
    {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            status = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProjectStatusM"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will play around with it a bit and if it works better, then I will give you upvote. : )

Comment: @RGdent Ok. Good luck.