# WPF just add new items to Collection that is binded to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, itemscontrol

In `ItemsControl` I have placed my Collection of Items. As this collection can be very huge, I try to implement some paging - When scroll to the end of visible scroll area, add new items to `ItemsControl`.

Detecting of scroll bottom I've used from this answers [How to find that ScrollViewer is scrolled to the end in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793717/how-to-find-that-scrollviewer-is-scrolled-to-the-end-in-wpf)

But I need to implement `Adding` of items.

```
if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight &&
                _productsViewModel.ProductTotal > pageCount*ConfigurationProvider.ItemsPerProductPage)
            {
                pageCount++;
                _productsViewModel.RunPaginationWorker(pageCount);
            }
```

Items are added in BG Worker. As parameter I send `pageNumber` which is amount of times when user scroll to the end of scroll.

In BG CompleteWork event, I receive items and try to bind them to Property which is binded to `ItemsControl`

```
var items= (e.Result) as List<ItemDto>;
Items.AddRange(items);
OnPropertyChanged("Items");
```

But this doesn't work, it seems like Property `Items` isn't changed.

---

```
public List<ItemDto> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set
            {
                _items= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }
```

And Xaml Binding

```
<ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="650" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,40,10,0" Name="Items" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AlternationCount="{Binding Path=Items.Count,FallbackValue='100'}">
...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Normally you use an ObservableCollection as the type for Items. What are you using now? If you use an ObservableCollection, the event handling should be done implicitly without having to call any OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: Items is not an observable collection, is it? ObservableCollection doesn't have an AddRange method.

Comment: If you have huge amount of items, you should use Binding. Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35577155/1560697)

Comment: @demo Can you show your binding?

Comment: @Valentin, please check it in question now

Comment: @demo Try to use `ObservableCollection`, instead of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` as  it implements the interfaces:

- INotifyCollectionChanged
- INotifyPropertyChanged

As such it is very useful when you want to know when the collection has changed. An event is triggered that will tell the user what entries have been added/removed or moved.

If you want to have method `AddRange()`, then just copy this code:

```
private ObservableCollection<ItemDto> _items=new ObservableCollection<ItemDto>();
public ObservableCollection<ItemDto> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
       _items= value;
       OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}

public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    foreach (var i in collection)
    {
        Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you want just take the last items, I would suggest you `linq` methods. For example, you can skip 10 items and take the next 10 items:

```
Items=Items.Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

**Update 1:**

When you adding new items to collection and you do not want draw new items, then you should just add `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`. This will reduce the numbers of times to re-render new  controls.

Comment: But then I can't just add new items. I need to reinitialize `Items` with new Collection

Comment: @demo Do you mean that when you add new items then you should create new collection?

Comment: I just want to render new items in itemsControl. Old ones I just want to skip for better performance

Comment: About Update - I want to render first 10 elements (as example) then, when scroll to the bottom, add new 10 elements etc. While do it, I don't want to re-render first 10 elements, just render new 10 elements.

Comment: Or binder don't understand that I just add few items and there is no need to rebind old items?